# Assign abstract constant properties to a mock

Tags: matlab, unit-testing, mocking

I am working on a project with a hierarchy of classes like this:

```
% Standard class that has properties and methods shared by all classes in the project
classdef StandardClass < handle
    properties (Constant, Abstract)
        displayName
    end
end
```

---

```
% Abstract class that defines the interface for a particular set of concrete classes
classdef AbstractClass < StandardClass
    methods
        function name = getDisplayName(obj)
            name = obj.displayName;
        end
    end
end
```

---

```
% Actual implementation of the concrete class
classdef ConcreteClass < AbstractClass
    properties (Constant)
        displayName = 'My Concrete Class'
    end
end
```

With this MWE, I can create an instance of the concrete class and I can query the displayName.

Now, I want to test *another* class that interfaces with my `AbstractClass`. Rather than write a test that loops through each concrete class and tests the interface, I'd like to use the new mocking framework to make a mock using my `AbstractClass` as a template:

```
classdef UnitTest < matlab.mock.TestCase
    methods (Test)
        function testDisplay(obj)
            concrete = createMock(obj, ?AbstractClass);

            % My test here
        end
    end
end
```

This ends with the error:

```
---------
Error ID:
---------
'MATLAB:mock:MockContext:NonDefaultPropertyAttribute'

--------------
Error Details:
--------------
Error using matlab.mock.internal.MockContext>validateAbstractProperties (line 623)
Unable to create a mock for the 'AbstractClass' class because Abstract property 'displayName' has a non-default value for its 'Constant' attribute.
```

Well, that's a bummer. I guess I get it, though. The mock has no way of knowing how to assign the abstract property, so I add:

```
properties (Constant)
    displayName = 'Abstract Class';
end
```

to my `AbstractClass`. Then when I run my test, my mock gets created and the unit test runs fine. However, if I then go to try to create the concrete class outside the test framework:

```
>> test = ConcreteClass();
Error using ConcreteClass
Cannot define property 'displayName' in class 'ConcreteClass' because the property has already been defined in the superclass 'AbstractClass'.
```

So I'm stuck in a catch-22. I can get the mock to work and successfully run a unit test only if I break the code so it doesn't run.

The code base I'm working with has a lot of different abstract classes that are based on our standard class. Is there any way to tell the mocking framework how to assign `(Abstract, Constant)` properties when calling `createMock` using a template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: As of MATLAB R2018a, this is possible using the `'DefaultPropertyValues'` name/value pair with the `createMock` method.

For example:

```
classdef UnitTest < matlab.mock.TestCase
    methods (Test)
        function testDisplay(testCase)
            concrete = createMock(testCase, ?AbstractClass, ...
                'DefaultPropertyValues',struct('displayName','Abstract Class'));

            % My test here
        end
    end
end
```

For more information, here's the relevant documentation page:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mock.testcase.createmock.html?searchHighlight=DefaultPropertyValues

---

### Original answer for prior releases

As you've discovered, there is no way to create a mock for a class with an Abstract, Constant property, but this is a feature we will consider for a future release.

Here's a workaround:

As of MATLAB R2017b, you can create mocks for classes with Abstract, Static methods:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?searchHighlight=Mocking%20Framework%3A&s_tid=doc_srchtitle

So, you could restructure the code to use a Static method instead of a Constant property:

```
% Standard class that has properties and methods shared by all classes in the project
classdef StandardClass < handle
    methods (Abstract, Hidden, Static)
        name = getDisplayNameInternal
    end
end


% Abstract class that defines the interface for a particular set of concrete classes
classdef AbstractClass < StandardClass
    methods
        function name = getDisplayName(obj)
            name = obj.getDisplayNameInternal;
        end
    end
end

% Actual implementation of the concrete class
classdef ConcreteClass < AbstractClass
    methods (Hidden, Static)
        function name = getDisplayNameInternal
            name = 'My Concrete Class';
        end
    end
end
```

You can then create a mock:

```
[concrete, behavior] = createMock(obj, ?AbstractClass);
assignOutputsWhen(obj, withAnyInputs(behavior.getDisplayNameInternal), 'My mock class');
```

which implements the desired behavior:

```
>> concrete.getDisplayName
ans =
    'My mock class'
```